# How to upload a csv file into firebase and how to get the data of the uploaded file in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working on an ioinc2 and angular2 project.I am using firebase for backend support.I had a requirement of uploading .csv files containing mobile numbers data into the firebase and have to use the uploaded file data in a rest api.I had implemented the uploading of image files into the firebase.But I don't have any information regarding to the .csv files uploading into the firebase.How can I upload .csv files into firebase in angular2?